# How can I declare an array of an interface as a Typescript function parameter?

Tags: typescript

I declared the following:

```
ExamTypeId = {
    All: {
        id: this.examTypeSelectId,
        text: 'Exam Type: All',
        val: 0
    }
}
```

and an interface:

```
export interface IEnumElement {
    id: string;
    text: string;
    val: number
}
```

A function that I call:

```
checkGrid(expectedCount: number, row: string, params: IEnumElement[]) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now I am trying to call my function like this:

```
page.checkGrid(4, page.gridRow,  [page.ExamStatusId.All, page.ExamTypeId.All]);
```

It is giving me a java exception error which I think is related to the way I am calling the function. Can someone confirm if
this is the correct way to set the type for an array of IEnumElement?

Comment: You get a runtime error right? Or an error during the compilation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have supplied, you have used:

```
page.ExamStatusId.All
```

But `ExamStatusId` isn't defined anywhere... did you mean to use `ExamTypeId`?

In any case, if there is an `ExamStatusId` property, it would also have to contain an `All` element that has the same structure as `IEnumElement`.

If the error is at runtime, make sure you have included all of the JavaScript files at runtime (all the files, all with a `.js` extension and in the right order!)

If you are still stuck, can you share the error message?